# What's the best way to remotely admin MS ADAM?

Tags: remote, adam

I am setting up a new MS ADAM instance on a Win 2003 server. I want to be able to manager users and groups from my own Win Xp/7 workstations.

What's the best tool for doing this?  Is there a way to get just the ADAM ADSIEdit tool on my PC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[RSAT for Win7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9FF6E897-23CE-4A36-B7FC-D52065DE9960)
I believe for XP the tools are an option in the [ADAM installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9688f8b9-1034-4ef6-a3e5-2a2a57b5c8e4).